# Loading same value in inner HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I am trying to enter the below statement into HashMap

```
Input Line: Rainy#No:2 Sunny#No:3 Rainy#Yes:3 Sunny#Yes:2 Overcast#Yes:4
Expected Output:{Rainy={No=2,Yes=3},Rainy={No=3,Yes=2},Overcast={Yes=4}}
```

What I did so far is

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;


public class StackHash{

/**
*@paramargs
*/

staticConcurrentMap<String,HashMap<String,Integer>>map=newConcurrentHashMap<>();
public static final String TAB="\t";
public static final String SPACE=" ";
public static final String HASH="#";
public static final String COLON=":";
public static void main(String[]args){
//TODOAuto-generatedmethodstub

Stringline="Rainy#No:2 Sunny#No:3 Rainy#Yes:3 Sunny#Yes:2 Overcast#Yes:4";
StringTokenizerst=newStringTokenizer(line,SPACE);
HashMap<String,Integer>attibuteCollect=newHashMap<String,Integer>();
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
 Stringtoken1=st.nextToken();
 String[]parts=token1.split(HASH);
 String[]parts1=parts[1].split(COLON);
 attibuteCollect.put(parts1[0],Integer.parseInt(parts1[1]));
 if(map.isEmpty()){
   map.put(parts[0],attibuteCollect);
 }
 else{
   for(Map.Entry<String,HashMap<String,Integer>>entry:map.entrySet()){
     StringkeyMap=entry.getKey();
     if(keyMap.equals(parts[0])){
       map.put(keyMap,attibuteCollect);
     }
     else{
       map.put(parts[0],attibuteCollect);
     }
 }
}
}
System.out.println("finalmap"+map);
}
}
```

Output

```
map {Rainy={Yes=4, No=3}, Sunny={Yes=4, No=3}, Overcast={Yes=4, No=3}}
```

Am I doing anything wrong.

Please Suggest.

Comment: @Makoto This is not the exact duplicate. The duplicate marked question explaining about removing the item from map. Here in this case there is no remove method calling on iterator. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ The question applies to any structural modification of a collection while you are iterating over it. Sure, `Map#put()` is being called instead of `map.remove()`, but the cause of the problem is exactly the same.

Comment: @user3580294 I Got your point and now I'm not seeing any `ConcurrentModificationException` in OP's question :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Guess now that OP's question changed the point is moot... Although according to the javadoc `ConcurrentModificationExceptions` are not guaranteed to be thrown, and even then this code has undefined behavior, so this code not working right isn't that surprising to me

Comment: @user3580294 Thumbs up. Agreed. I tried to execute current code and giving some other exception :) Mismatching every where.

Comment: After changing to ConcurrentMap also  the values in inner hashmap is getting overwritten

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**

You got `ConcurrentModificationException` because, you have modified inner `attibuteCollect` map using `put` method while iterating over outer `map`.

**Solution:**

Use `ConcurrentHashMap` insted of `HashMap` to solve `ConcurrentModificationException`.

```
  ConcurrentMap<String, HashMap<String,Integer>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

Comment: @Masud: It didnt solved.again getting the same output
final map {Rainy={Yes=4, No=3}, Sunny={Yes=4, No=3}, Overcast={Yes=4, No=3}}

Comment: I think I have done some mistake in looping.but not able to fix it

Comment: @SreeVeni, Yes that is mistake. Please debug your code and see how your value changed.

Comment: @SreeVeni  Can you set up a IDEONE for your problem. Please give some working code. Running your code causing a different exception `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2 Sunny"`

Comment: @Masud: I edited the code as you suggested